# Block users from accessing anything outside home folder and run any executables on Windows

Tags: windows, profile, read-only, limits

I am facing a quite complex problem and I do not know how to approach it in the best way. In short I need to block access (browse, display, run etc.) to anything outside of the profile/home directory on Windows + block installation and execution of any programs or applications that are not currently installed on a system. Some kind of similar to removing X permission on Linux and read only. This should also include blocking of changing any system system settings like date as an example.

How to approach this in the best way by using GPO policies or any 3rd party software?

Can you please guide me in the right direction?

A nice addition to the above would be to block any executable ran from archives or self-unpacked exe's,

Thank you a lot upfront.

Comment: Make yourself familiar with Software Restriction Policies (SRP) feature of Windows.

Comment: I'd rather recommend AppLocker, Software Restriction Policies are deprecated and should not be used.